# Azdo Releases Powershell Inline vs File Path

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task, windows-server-2022

I am using Azure DevOps Deployment Group Agent to deploy Azure DevOps Releases Tasks.

Is there a way to utilize Azure DevOps built-in variables, such as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, within PowerShell files when executing them through the Azure DevOps Releases task, akin to their accessibility when using inline PowerShell within the same task?

**Background of the issue:**

The issue is that when I run Inline Powershell scripts, it works fine. But when I move the same script to a file and try to consume the file from the repo that is located in `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` which is the agent host server, it can not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run Azure DevOps built-in variables like `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` via a file on an on-prem agent, you need to add `$env` before the variable.
Here's an example of how you can access `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` in a PowerShell file:

```
$workingDirectory = $env:System_DefaultWorkingDirectory
Write-Host "Working Directory: $workingDirectory"
```

`$env` is valid and also applies to other Azure DevOps build-in variables in PowerShell when running in the same context.

Comment: nice to know that, or you could consider posting your solution [as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), and highlight it to benefit more developers